# Ranking MySQL search results based on relevance of other fields

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query that will check for all columns in the document table which contain the word that is being searched, and displays the matching user data that it is supposed to be linked to. However, my problem comes from trying to rank the search results based on relevance.

```
select distinct a.* 
  from application a, 
       document d 
 where (   d.`DocID`                    like "%president%" 
        or d.`AppID`                    like "%president%" 
        or d.`TypeID`                   like "%president%" 
        or d.`IDnum`                    like "%president%" 
        or d.`Activity`                 like "%president%" 
        or d.`Role/Position`            like "%president%" 
        or d.`Date`                     like "%president%" 
        or d.`Venue`                    like "%president%" 
        or d.`BriefDescription`         like "%president%" 
        or d.`NameoftheOrganization`    like "%president%" 
        or d.`TermofOffice`             like "%president%" 
        or d.`SpecialAward/Achievement` like "%president%" 
        or d.`Attachments`              like "%president%" 
        or d.`Attachmentsb`             like "%president%" 
        or d.`Attachmentsc`             like "%president%" 
        or d.`Remarks`                  like "%president%" ) 
       and d.`AppID` = a.`AppId`
```

The above statement does the job when relevance is not an issue, however, what I would like to accomplish is that if the word "president" is found, I would need to rank its relevance also based on other fields in the row that would contain certain words like national, international, etc(these keywords will not be stored in a database, they can be written into the query itself if needed)

Example: A person with one row containing "President" in Role/Position and "International" in BriefDescription would be ranked higher than someone with 2 rows containing "President" in Role/Position and "Local" in BriefDescription. Keyword ranking isn't bound just the BriefDescription field as other fields may also contain the said keyword.

Different example: If I searched for "awardee", a person with "International Awardee" in any of the fields would be ranked higher than someone with "National Awardee".

I have read about FULLTEXT searches from looking around the web looking for a solution that applied to my setup, but I am still very unsure of how to begin and approach my problem, given that most examples were for queries that did not exceed comparing 2 or 3 fields at most. If anyone could steer me in the right direction, it would be of much help.

Comment: your relevance rules are too complicated to handle with a simple fulltext index. fulltext can give a relevance score for a match, but not when you want to make fields score differently. you'd need multiple fulltext indexes and multiple fulltext searches to accomplish that. Plus, `somefield like 'string'` is a pointless match. `like` is used for wildcard searches. you don't have any. it's no different than saying `somefield='string'`.

Comment: Oops. I put the wrong query above (I made it an option to search for the word in a phrase or just the word exactly. Turns out I pasted the one that only searched for an exact match. Editing...) I do use wildcards in my query.

Comment: it's a hideous hack and makes for truly ugly-to-read queries, but `select (somefield like '%foo%') + (otherfield like '%foo%') AS score1, etc...` works. the true/false boolean results of the like matches can get added up as normal 0/1 integers, and you generate scores that way. but again, the query becomes extremely ugly to read as you add more and more scoring rules.

Comment: I'll try this. I just wanted to know though, you say my relevance rules are too complicated to be handled with a simple fulltext index. To what extent of a rule /can/ a simple fulltext index handle?

Comment: mysql can give relevance scores, but the actual values of the scores are probably not directly comparable to other scores from similar-but-different fulltext searches. one might give you a 0->1 range, the other might return 1->20 or whatever.